# How to loop through nested objects in jsx react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with react I want to show some dynamic content on UI but unable to loop the data as I am newbie so finding this difficult to do

```
 state={
dashboardManpowerCount:{
        "CurrentMonth": {
          "Total No of employes": 25,
          "Ariving": 10,
          "Exited": 8
        },
        "PreviousMonth": {
          "Total No of employes": 25,
          "Ariving": 10,
          "Exited": 8
        }
      }
           }

class currAndprevMonthcCounts extends Component {
render(){
const {dashboardManpowerCount} = this.state

return(
<div>
<div className="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                    <div className="row">
                       <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
                       <h6>Previous Month</h6>
                    <h2>395</h2> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">

                    <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mt-2"
                    >+7 Ariving</span>
                    <br></br>

                    <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mt-3">-3 Exiting</span> 

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <div className="row">
                       <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
                    <h6>Previous Month</h6>
                    <h2>395</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">

                    <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mt-2">+5 Ariving</span>
                    <br></br>

                    <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mt-3">-3 Exiting</span> 

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
</div>
)
}

}
```

there  are two options current month data and previous month data I want to loop through the object and render in place of static content in my jsx

this is how [image: I am rendering this]

**Edit / Update**

I think I am missing something here is working example with static data on UI [This is what I am trying to get](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-cache-66ryr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `object.keys` or `object.entries` to loop through the properties of an object.

```
  render() {
    const { dashboardManpowerCount } = this.state;
    const dashboardManpowerCountArray = Object.entries(dashboardManpowerCount);

    return (
      <div>
        {dashboardManpowerCountArray.map(arr => {
          return (
            <div key={arr[0]}>
              <h3>{arr[0]}</h3>
              {Object.entries(arr[1]).map(monthArr => {
                return (
                  <span key={monthArr[0]} style={{ display: "block" }}>{`${
                    monthArr[0]
                  } ${monthArr[1]}`}</span>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-evwwix?file=index.js). Obviously change the styling and tags how you like.

**update**

Here's the jsx you can use to display your data-

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

class Events extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dashboardManpowerCount: {
      CurrentMonth: {
        "Total No of employes": 25,
        Ariving: 10,
        Exited: 8
      },
      PreviousMonth: {
        "Total No of employes": 25,
        Ariving: 10,
        Exited: 8
      }
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="divParent row container">
        {Object.entries(this.state.dashboardManpowerCount).map(
          ([monthName, monthData]) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
                    <h6>{monthName}</h6>
                    <h2>{monthData["Total No of employes"]}</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">
                    <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mt-2">
                      {`+${monthData.Ariving} Ariving`}
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary mt-3">
                      {`-${monthData.Ariving} Exiting`}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Events />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But this time the component is not fully dynamic. If your object's schema changes in the future you will have to change the jsx too.

Comment: It seems to be very complicated as i am not able to put the styling as it was ( grid system)

Comment: Please cvheck my edit I have attached the code-sandbox link for referral

Comment: @dheerajkumar You can open the stackblitz link in my answer and customize the styling and then add it to your project. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: yes I ahve tried editing your code, but look I don't need the total no of employee only this count I need, tehre I am stuck you can check the link I have shared

Comment: Well, what's stopping you from displaying the count you need? The data you used in the codesandbox is not in the state.

Comment: yup that one is just for referral, the stoping part is 'Total No of employe' this text I don't want to show just count.

Comment: @dheerajkumar Updated my answer with the styling you wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210570/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-ramesh).